# Is " SQL Helper Class " in Microsoft Application Blocks for .NET is excellent?

Tags: asp.net, sql, application-blocks

from years go i use "SQL Helper" class that exist in Microsoft Application Blocks for .NET and i used it for about 1 year in many projects but after that many senior recommend me not to use as it's have many problems in big projects and i let it but know in a new company they want to use it in a projects ...
 Could any make his recommendations about it / and if it's really excellent to use it have already issues ?
Is there any other good solution rather than SQL Helper ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the SQL Helper class and newer DAAB/Enterprise Library in many projects before. I would suggest that you use the right tool for the right job. Alternatives include

- NHibernate
- LINQtoSQL
- Entity Framework
- Enterprise Library
- My Generation (and various plug-in frameworks like Gentle)
- ADO.NET... the list goes one

Answer (score 0):

I've used that application block and modified versions of it in a number of projects (large and small), it makes a great framework to build your data tier around in my opinion.  Just don't treat it as an end all framework and expand it when needed.