# Data access wrapper

Tags: vb.net

I am looking at the SQLHelper class: https://appsimplicity.googlecode.com/svn-history/r217/MetaDataExtractor/SchemaDiscovery/AppSimplicity.SchemaDiscovery.Providers/SQLServer/DataAccess/SQLHelper.vb.

I want to use an SQLHelper to connect to Oracle databases and SQL Server databases (the choice is made at runtime).

I believe I have two options:

1. Amend the code to use interfaces rather than classes e.g. dbCommand instead of SQLCommand
2. Overload some of the functions e.g. executeReader to accept Oracle connection objects

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so I was wandering if there are any other alternative options.  Are there any alternative options? If there are no alternative options, then which option is best?

I read this post, which talks about other data access solutions available: [Is " SQL Helper Class " in Microsoft Application Blocks for .NET is excellent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122448/is-sql-helper-class-in-microsoft-application-blocks-for-net-is-excellent)

The project I am working on uses ADO.NET and this is the API I want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two classes I use that mimic that pattern in EntLib5 without needing to use the whole entlib5 data library and it's dependencies. The two example call use nonqueries, but there are db methods for scalar and dataset. You could also add one for datareader pretty easy.

**Example of calling classes with a transaction**

```
 Private Sub SubmitEntity(ByVal entity As Entity)

        Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase()

        db.ConnectionString = Me.ConnectionString

        Dim transaction As SqlTransaction = Nothing

        Dim cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.MystoredProc")

        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "entityData", SqlDbType.VarChar, entity.Data)
        db.AddInParameter(cmd, "enitityId", SqlDbType.Int, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output)

        Try

            transaction = db.Transaction

            db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, db.Transaction)

            transaction.Commit()

            db.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

            If transaction IsNot Nothing Then
                transaction.Rollback()
            End If

            If db IsNot Nothing AndAlso db.Connection IsNot Nothing Then
                db.Dispose()
            End If

        End Try

    End Sub
```

**Example of calling with no transaction**

```
    Private Sub SubmitEntity(ByVal entity As Entity)

    Dim db As Database = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("the connection string")

    Dim cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("dbo.MystoredProc")

    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "entityData", SqlDbType.VarChar, entity.Data)
    db.AddInParameter(cmd, "enitityId", SqlDbType.Int, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Output)

    db.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd, db.Transaction)

End Sub
```

**DatabaseFactory Class**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Friend Class DatabaseFactory

    Private Shared Property Connection As SqlConnection

    Friend Shared Function CreateDatabase(ByVal connectionString As String) As Database

        If Connection Is Nothing OrElse Connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open OrElse Connection.ConnectionString <> connectionString Then

            'create a new SqlConnection, and assign the connection string property
            Connection = New SqlConnection With
                {
                    .ConnectionString = connectionString
                }

            'connect to the Sql database
            Connection.Open()

        End If

        'return the database with an open connection
        Return New Database With {.Connection = Connection, .ConnectionString = connectionString}

    End Function

    Friend Shared Function CreateDatabase() As Database

        Return New Database

    End Function

End Class
```

**Database Class**

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Friend Class Database

    Friend Property ConnectionString As String

    Private ConnectionValue As SqlConnection
    Friend Property Connection As SqlConnection
        Get
            If Me.ConnectionValue Is Nothing OrElse Me.ConnectionValue.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.ConnectionString) Then
                    'create a new SqlConnection, and assign the connection string property
                    Me.ConnectionValue = New SqlConnection With
                        {
                            .ConnectionString = ConnectionString
                        }

                    'connect to the Sql database
                    Me.ConnectionValue.Open()
                Else
                    Throw New Exception("A connection string must be provided.")
                End If
            End If
            Return Me.ConnectionValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SqlConnection)
            Me.ConnectionValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private TransactionValue As SqlTransaction
    Friend Property Transaction As SqlTransaction
        Get
            If TransactionValue Is Nothing Then
                If Me.Connection IsNot Nothing Then
                    Me.TransactionValue = Me.Connection.BeginTransaction
                Else
                    Throw New Exception("No open connection exists.")
                End If
            End If
            Return Me.TransactionValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As SqlTransaction)
            Me.TransactionValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend Function GetStoredProcCommand(ByVal storedProcName As String) As SqlCommand

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand() With
            {
                .CommandText = storedProcName,
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
                .Connection = Me.Connection
            }

        Return cmd

    End Function

    Friend Function GetSqlStringCommand(ByVal query As String) As SqlCommand

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand() With
            {
                .CommandText = query,
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                .Connection = Me.Connection
            }

        Return cmd

    End Function

    Friend Sub AddInParameter(ByRef cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal paramterName As String, ByVal sqlDbType As SqlDbType, ByVal value As Object, Optional ByVal direction As ParameterDirection = ParameterDirection.Input)

        Dim para As New SqlParameter With
            {
                .Value = value,
                .ParameterName = If(Not paramterName.StartsWith("@"), String.Format("@{0}", paramterName), paramterName),
                .SqlDbType = sqlDbType,
                .Direction = direction
            }

        cmd.Parameters.Add(para)

    End Sub

    Friend Sub ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal transaction As SqlTransaction)

        cmd.Transaction = transaction

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Sub

    Friend Sub ExecuteNonQuery(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand)

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    End Sub

    Friend Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal transaction As SqlTransaction) As Object

        cmd.Transaction = transaction

        Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    End Function

    Friend Function ExecuteScalar(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As Object

        Return cmd.ExecuteScalar()

    End Function

    Friend Function ExecuteDataSet(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal transaction As SqlTransaction) As DataSet

        cmd.Transaction = transaction

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd

        Dim dSet As New DataSet

        adapter.Fill(dSet)

        adapter.Dispose()

        Return dSet

    End Function

    Friend Function ExecuteDataSet(ByVal cmd As SqlCommand) As DataSet

        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd

        Dim dSet As New DataSet

        adapter.Fill(dSet)

        adapter.Dispose()

        Return dSet

    End Function

    Friend Sub Dispose()
        Me.Connection.Close()
        Me.Connection.Dispose()
    End Sub


End Class
```